# SQLAlchemy force Left Join

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a little problem. I have two SQL tables (ip and client) bound by a third one (ip_client). I did not use the many to many relationships shipped with SQLAlchemy because of complex filtering occurring on some of my queries.

Everything is fine except for one silly use case. I want to list all the IP without clients, and I can't do it without an outer join.

Outer Join takes several seconds where the same query with Left Join is instant. But impossible to avoid the INNER JOIN created by SQL Alchemy. I tried all relationships, and to move my foreign keys but it keeps an INNER JOIN.

Based on the same issue, whenever I try to list all my ips with a column showing the number of clients, the query won't return ips with 0 clients (natural behavior for an INNER JOIN).

Is there a way to force that ?

By the way this is my query :

```
query = (session.query(Ip, func.count(Client.id))
    .join(ClientIp, ClientIp.ip_id==Ip.id)
    .join(Client, Client.id==ClientIp.client_id)
    .group_by(Ip.id))
```

Is there a trick in the query creation or the join function to force a LEFT JOIN ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just use [`outerjoin`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.outerjoin) instead of `join` where appropriate:

```
query = (session.query(Ip, func.count(Client.id)).
    outerjoin(ClientIp, ClientIp.ip_id==Ip.id).
    outerjoin(Client, Client.id==ClientIp.client_id).
    group_by(Ip.id)
)
```

Performance of an `OUTER JOIN` is another issue, where having `indices` on `ForeignKey` columns might be of tremendous help.

Comment: I created an index and this is really fast now, though it doesn't change my problem with the count (second issue). Outer join will only return 0, Inner JOIN will only return > 0. How do I retrieve everything in only one query ?

Comment: I do not think that your statement regarding the `OUTER JOIN` returning only 0 is correct. In fact, `OUTER JOIN` should return all. Have you tried it?

Comment: You're right, I did only outer join on one of my two joins. Working fine with two of them. Thanks a lot !